# how to use pdf reader module in drupal?

Tags: files

im trying to make a simple pdf viewer or reader website running locally on my computer. Ive used the pdf reader, follow the instruction in README.TXT but still i can't use this. I can't seem to find the pdf reader. Any suggestion on how to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable pdf module and create a file field in the content type where you want pdf to be visible and there are two option to display PDF file in the field display setting, select which ever you require. (You need to use the latest pdf.js to use first page display).

Note: you need to download pdf.js manually and add in project directory

Hope you are following this,
http://drupalcode.org/project/pdf.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt

Comment: so what if i copy my site on a flash disk and run on other computer, then to be able to run, i should perform first the extension creation ?